# find selected child with .on method

Tags: jquery

how can i get some property (i.e "id"), of child selector element?
Im using .on() method because elemenets are created by ajax call.
`$(this).attr('id');` returns id of selector, but how to get the one of child selector? tried: `$(this).find(':selected').attr('id');` but it does not helps.
code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userBtn = $(".userButton");
    $(".listBox").on("click", userBtn, function () {
        var userId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(userId);
    });
});
```

Comment: please show your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter for the click handler is `child selector` but you're passing the jQuery wrapped object.

```js
$(".listBox").on("click",".userButton",function(){
             var userId=$(this).attr('id');
             alert(userId);
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listBox">
 <li class="userButton" id="btn1">Button 1</li>
 <li class="userButton" id="btn2">Button 2</li>
 <li class="userButton" id="btn3">Button 3</li>
</ul>
```